# How to get specific records and it's all related records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have more than 3 tables. But for simplicity, let take 3 Products, ProductBrands and ProductAttributes. Every poduct have zero or more brands and zero or more attributes. Now I have,

```
SELECT P.Name,P.ID, P.Desc FROM Products
```

But I want to select all product attributes and brands in the same SQL. I am thinking this,

```
SELECT P.Name,P.ID, P.Desc, GetProductAttributesInJSONOrXML(P.ID), GetProductBrandsInJSONOrXML(P.ID)   FROM Products
```

How to create GetProductAttributesInJSONOrXML and GetProductBrandsInJSONOrXML funstions? So that in my app I can easily deserilize the xml or json. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Create the json/xml in your app, not at the DB level. Just select all the data you need. Though you can select xml with SQL server, look up the for xml clause.

Comment: This blog link may be a useful reference: [SQL to JSON](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/)

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, can you please it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select data in SQL Server as XML by use of the [FOR XML clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Such a query will give you back a single row with a single column containing the generated XML. [Here's an example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/).

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT Product.Name, Product.ID, Product.Desc, Attribs.Attribute, Brands.Brand 
FROM Products Product
LEFT JOIN ProductBrands Brands ON Product.ID = Brands.ProductID
LEFT JOIN ProductAttributes Attribs ON Product.ID = Attribs.ProductID
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

To get XML schema something like this, with one Product group for each row:

```
<Product>
  <Name></Name>
  <ID></ID>
  <Desc></Desc>
  <Attribs>
    <Attribute></Attribute>
  </Attribs>
  <Brands>
    <Brand></Brand>
  </Brands>
</Product>
...
```

There are a lot of different options with the clause to get the schema formatted exactly the way you want, though it might take a bit of work for more complicated designs.

There's no way to generate JSON on SQL Server, short of using code to explicitly generate it with text functions. This would be complicated and probably not perform very well, since SQL Server is not optimized for text processing. Generating JSON is best done at the application level.

If you need to emit both JSON and XML, I suggest generating both at the application level. This allows needing only one SQL query to get your data, and keeping the data formatting code in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in SQL server, here are the options:

1. Generate JSON String in Queries
2. Store JSON string in a column as string for faster rendering

You can also do it in java by using the JSON libarary mentioned in previous answer.